# React-Native Picker TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, picker

I am trying to display data in picker (react-native) but the above error is displaying if I try to map the this.state.dataSource
I don't understand what seems to be the problem

I have tried almost all the same type questions on Stackoverflow but none of them seems to work

```
 constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            dataSource: [],
            PickerValueHolder: '',

        }

    }
```

```
componentDidMount() {

  var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/defects/' + 'defects'+ '.json';
  console.log(path);
  // write the file
  return RNFS.readFile(path, 'utf8')
    .then((success) => {
      newData = JSON.parse(success);
      dataSource = newData[0].results.recordset;
      dataSource = JSON.stringify(dataSource)
      console.log("datasource "+dataSource); 
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
}
```

console.log("datasource "+dataSource); output

```
[{"success":true,"results":{"recordsets":[[{"DefectID":2,"Defect":"Damage","Description":"Crack in walls"}]],"recordset":[{"DefectID":2,"Defect":"Damage","Description":"Crack in walls"}],"output":{},"rowsAffected":[1],"returnValue":0}}]
```

Picker code

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.PickerValueHolder}
  style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
  onValueChange={
    (itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ PickerValueHolder: itemValue })}
>
  {console.log("Picker " + this.state.dataSource)}
  {this.state.dataSource.map((item, key) => {
    <Picker.Item label={item.defect} value={item.defect} key={key} />
    }
  )}
</Picker>
```

{console.log("Picker " + this.state.dataSource)} output

`[{"DefectID":2,"Defect":"Damage","Description":"Crack in walls"}]`

error TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Expected output:  the data should get inflated in picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `RNFS.readFile(path, 'utf8')` is async, the render method will most likely be called before `this.state.dataSource` has been populated. `this.state.dataSource` will be `null` initially, so you need to set that within your `constructor`.

```
// ...
constructor() {
  this.state = {
    dataSource: []
  }
}
```

#### Update

Within your question, you are stringifying `dataSource` and assinging that within state. `Strings` don't have the `map` function within JavaScript, so remove that offending code, as per below.

```
  return RNFS.readFile(path, 'utf8')
    .then((success) => {
      newData = JSON.parse(success);
      dataSource = newData[0].results.recordset;
      console.log("datasource "+JSON.stringify(dataSource)); 
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
```

Comment: after setting the dataSource to the constructor I am getting "TypeError: this.state.dataSource.map is not a function"

Comment: You're stringifying the `dataSource` within `readFile` async function. Can you remove that (i.e. remove `dataSource = JSON.stringify(dataSource)`)

Comment: If you want to maintain the `console.log` within the `readFile` function, change it to `console.log("datasource "+JSON.stringify(dataSource));`